# How could I print the highest score and name of student grades using python?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Using python I'm creating a code that receives a list of lists as parameter. This list of lists contains names and grades of students. The function also must print the name of the student with the best grade and its best grade. When I created the code and try to run it nothing occurs is there a way to improve my code? My desired output would be "The best student is: Caroline with a 9.6"

```
students=[["steve", 9.0], ["ben", 9.5], ["Caroline",9.6],["Tim", 9.1]]
highest_grade=[]
lowest_grade=[]
def best():
    i = 1
    max = min = students[0]
    # first, calculate the max and min.
    while i < len(students):  # (possible improvement: replace this with a for loop)
        if students[i] > max:
          max = students[i]    # replace max with the new max
        if students[i] < min:
            min = students[i]    # replace min with the new min
     i += 1
highest_grade.append(max)
lowest_grade.append(min)
print("The best student is:",best())
```

Comment: You should indent `i += 1` such that it is aligned with the `if` above. Currently your `while` loop is an endless one because `i` never changes inside the loop. Also you don't return `max` from your function and comparing whole tuples (e.g. `["steve", 9.0]`) instead of only the scores.

Comment: Note that `students[i]` is not actually the score for the i'th student. Also, avoid shadowing Python keywords and built-in function names such as min and max.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.
Your posted code dies on an indentation error, and you haven't shown any attempt to trace the problem.  If nothing else, insert a couple of strategically-placed `print` commands to trace the program flow and data values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you could do to improve it. You find the min score but don't use it, so I'm not sure if you need it. If you do need it, you could add it to your `return` statement. Here's a suggested way to do it that should be easy to follow:

```
students = [["steve", 9.0], ["ben", 9.5], ["Caroline", 9.6], ["Tim", 9.1]]


def best(students):
    highest_grade_name = None
    lowest_grade_name = None
    my_max_score = -float("inf")
    my_min_score = float("inf")
    for name, score in students:
        if score > my_max_score:
            my_max_score = score
            highest_grade_name = name
        if score < my_min_score:
            my_min_score = score
            lowest_grade_name = name
    return my_max_score, highest_grade_name


best_name, best_score = best(students)
print(f"The best student is {best_name} with a score of {best_score}")
```

Comment: this is perfect! I just have one question, which is why for the max score did you put -float("inf")?

Comment: Did you understand what I did for the min score? I started with infinity so that the other values would be sure to be lower, thus they would become the new min. For the max score, it's just the opposite. I started with negative infinity so the other values would be sure to be higher.

Comment: Gotcha! I saw the min score starting with an infinity but now understand why you did the opposite for the max score! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`max(students,key=lambda x:x[1])`

I think would work

Answer (score 0):

There could be quite a few improvements to this piece of code. Firstly, it would be far better if the students array was a dict, but it's understandable if it absolutely has to be an array of arrays.

Secondly, you're right, you should do this with a for loop:

```py
def best_student_grade():
    highest_grade = 0 # "max" is a terrible name for a variable
    for student, grade in student:
        if grade > highest_grade:
             grade = highest_grade
             best_student = student
    return highest_grade, best_student

bstudent, bgrade = best_student_grade()

print(f"The best student is: {bstudent} with a {bgrade}")
```

You could even do this with a list comprehension, but I will leave that as an exercise to the reader.

In all honesty, I think it would benefit you in a lot of ways to read some introductory python or programming books.